# How to disable XML External Entity(XEE) processing in SAXBuilder which using com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, owasp

Here is my snippet:

```
public static SAXBuilder createBuilder(@NotNull final String schemaPath)  {


     final SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder("com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser", true);
    builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", true);
    builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);


    builder.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl",true);
    builder.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
    builder.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
    builder.setExpandEntities(false);
    builder.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/schema/external-noNamespaceSchemaLocation", schemaPath);
    builder.setEntityResolver(getEntityResolver());
    return builder;
}
```

I have spent some time searching, but there's not much left out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified the root cause of this problem. It was because of  `processContents="lax"` attribute in my xsd